# Unable to exclude auto response emails from the count

Tags: apex, email, controller, custom-controller, email2case

I have a requirement where a custom field (Number_of_Emails__c) on cases will be updated with total number of emailmessages related to that case.

Now, I need to exclude auto response email from that count.

Below is my code:

```
List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
        for (EmailMessage em : newList) {
            caseIds.add(em.parentId);
        }
        System.debug('parent case ids: ' + caseIds);
    Map<Id, Case> parentCases = new Map<Id, Case>([
                SELECT Id, Team__c,  Number_of_Emails__c,
                    (SELECT Id, ParentId,ToAddress, Subject FROM EmailMessages) 
                FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds
            ]);
            System.debug('parent case map: ' + parentCases);
    
            List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();
            for (Case c : parentCases.values()) {
                System.debug('parent case: ' + c);
                if (c.EmailMessages != null && c.EmailMessages[0].ToAddress != 'randomautoresponsemailid@gmail.com') {
                        c.Number_of_Emails__c = c.EmailMessages.size();
                        casesToUpdate.add(c);
                }
            }
```

Above code isnt giving me any error but it is still counting auto response email on Number_of_Emails__c field.

Can anyone please help me out here to get this resolved

Comment: It seems you are checking ToAddress of only first EmailMessages- EmailMessages[0].ToAddress . You need to iterate all the EmailMessages record for a case and check how many ToAddress != randomautoresponsemailid@gmail.com

Comment: auto response email will be sent only once and that too when a new case is opened. Is there any way i can exclude only that auto response emailmessage?

Comment: In that scenario , c.Number_of_Emails__c = c.EmailMessages.size() - 1 . EmailMessages will have the list of all the email and if it's know that auto response rule will be sent only once, then you can do c.Number_of_Emails__c = c.EmailMessages.size() - 1